# WordPress Plugins Upload Defaults to 777 permissions

Tags: wordpress, nginx, chmod, php

I'm currently using WordPress 3.5 on nginx/1.2.6 with PHP-FPM web server setup on my VPS.
I noticed a major security problem whenever I upload a wordpress plugin, it would default all the directories and files to 777 permissions. This would mean that I would need to correct these file permissions manually.
I was wondering if anyone else out there had experienced this or has an idea what is causing this and how to fix it so it properly sets the correct permissions.

Any supportive advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `chmod -R` isn't too manual.

Comment: how do I make it so that it's recursively chmod 755 only for folders and 644 for files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only having a folder with 777 permission doesn't mean a security issue. If there is a buggy uploader PHP, then hackers could put a backdoor file to those folders. AFAIK wordpress needs writable folders for uploading and installing plugins. If you keep your wordpress up-to-date and if you don't have a buggy PHP uploader, you are not at risk.

Comment: Still, I find it weird that before I moved my WordPress setup from another web host to a vps, that all the plugin files/folders were set to 755, but now that I've transferred my WordPress, all new plugins uploaded are automatically set to 777, which I find a bit odd...
Even if 777 doesn't exactly make it insecure, I'd rather be cautious. Is there specific settings that I could change so that it  goes back to setting permissions at 755?

Comment: That's config of your hosting company, you may ask them to change it for your site if possible.

Comment: I'm using Amazon's EC2 running on an Ubuntu 12.04 instance and I would take it that I would need to configure that myself, but I do not know where exactly to look. When I do search, I keep getting the common problems to proper permissions for wordpress, but not exactly to what I'm looking for here.

Comment: Could you follow this guide to change default file creation permission? http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-set-the-default-file-and-directory-permissions.html

Comment: I tried following it and a few other similar tutorials where I would make the default umask to 022, but it's still not being applied so I think its being applied in some .conf file. I think I'm going to try and redo the whole setup again using another approach...

Comment: Do you have same plugins and same wordpress version in other server which doesn't change permissions to 777?

Comment: Yes, identical wordpress setup from the previous webhost.

Comment: even the versions? like php version, nginx version, os version, etc?

Comment: Oh no, the webservers were completely different. The old webhost was running on litespeed, not too sure about what os they were running.